# How to create different column in a CSV file?

Tags: file, csv, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to save in  a **CSV** *file* a **container** value.

I posted my code, I save in a file, but all container element are in a single column, I need to create a different column for each container element.

```
Set       set = new Set(Types::String);
CommaIo   myFile;
container myCon;
FileIoPermission perm;

 #File
 #Properties
 #AOT
 #define.ExampleFile(@"c:\MyFILE.csv")
 ;

perm = new FileIoPermission(#ExampleFile, #io_write);
perm.assert();
myFile= new CommaIo(#ExampleFile, #io_write);
myFile.outFieldDelimiter(',');

myCon= ["ColumnI", "ColumnII", "ColumnIII", "ColumnIV"];

file.writeExp(myCon);
```

So I will have container refill I wan to insert with sort under same column, looklike [image]

(first element in first column, second element in second columns etc...)

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: Could you show some code that writes values to the file? Your code currently only shows how the header line is written. Also make sure that your Excel uses commas as field separators and not another character like for example semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the container to container array and use it as shown below.

```
CommaIo   myFile;
container myCon[];
int i;
#File
#define.ExampleFile(@"c:\MyFILE.csv")

new FileIoPermission(#ExampleFile, #io_write).assert();
myFile = new CommaIo(#ExampleFile, #io_write);
myFile.outFieldDelimiter(',');

myCon[1] = ["ColumnI", "ColumnII", "ColumnIII", "ColumnIV"];
myCon[2] = ["elem_11", "elem_12", "elem_13", "elem_14"];
myCon[3] = ["elem_21", "elem_22", "elem_23", "elem_24"];

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    myFile.writeExp(myCon[i]);
}
```

[Click here to see the result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFnhV.png)

Comment: If you want a more simple example, you could use this `myFile.writeExp([con2str(myCont)]);`

Comment: Hi, very thanks, 
I appreciate your help, but I have all data values in the same column. I just copied the code. I'm wrong anything?

Comment: Are you writing to existing file or new file? Try writing to a new file. Also Can you try writing to a text file and see if the output is comma separated values?

Comment: What do you do after you open the file in Excel? Do you use the "Text to columns" function and specify that you have ',' as a delimiter?

Comment: Thanks for your time @Jan B. Kjeldsen .